# Erro na conexão com MySQL: Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ao conectar com o banco MYSQL usando a classe mysqli estou obtendo o erro:
**Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch**.

O erro ocorre qdo usada a versão 5.4.16 do PHP, na versão 5.6 já não ocorre o erro. Assim acredito que o erro está na versão do php, mas eu não tenho acesso para ajustar a versão do cliente por isso gastaria de tentar achar uma solução sem ter que trocar a versão do PHP.

A linha de conexão é:

```
$mysqli = new \mysqli($db['Host'], $db['User'], $db['Pass'], $db['Banco']);
```

Estou usando o composer, por isso a \ antes da conexão

Comment: Coloca também as versões do MySQL e do cliente do MySQL (via phpinfo())

Comment: O PHP e banco de dados estão em máquinas separadas?

Comment: Informações do PHP Info: MYSQL Client API version 5.6.31, MYSQLI Client API library version 5.6.31

Comment: creio que você mesmo já descobriu o problema: "O erro ocorre qdo usada a versão 5.4.16 do PHP, na versão 5.6 já não ocorre o erro" acho que só vai resolver quando deixar as duas versões iguais

Answer (score 1):

Troca o `php-mysql` pelo `php-mysqlnd` (a partir do MySQL 5.6)

```
yum remove php-mysql

yum install php-mysqlnd
```

ou

```
apt-get remove php5-mysql

apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comigo deu certo. Busquei a solução em [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)